# How to validate two textboxes at single button click using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to validate two textboxes at single button click using vb.net ?

it shows an error :

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If TextBox1 = "06:00:01 PM" & TextBox2.Text = "02:00:01 PM" Then
        MsgBox "Submit"
    End If
End Sub
```

Whatz wrong with my this code ?
I wanna validate two checkbox using if statement ... on Button click

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it always helps if you share what the error message is.  But there are just so many things wrong here:

1. & doesn't mean what you seem think it does.  It's the string concatenation operator and has nothing to do with a logical AND.  You want "And" or "AndAlso".
2. Don't forget to use your TextBox's `.Text` property.
3. Never NEVER **NEVER** call the MsgBox function in ASP.Net.  When deployed to an unattended web server (the normal case), it will display on a private desktop created just for that purpose *and block until clicked on*, which, given that it's showing on a private destkop, can never happen.
4. Your users will hate you for forcing them to manually enter such a specific datetime format.
5. Use the ASP.Net validation controls for this.  It's dirt simple.

Comment: +1 Important basic info here.  Read it, then read it again.  Here is a link for the ASP.NET validation controls if you need it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the value of a TextBox from just using `TextBox1`  To get the value, you need to use `TextBox1.Text`

Also, you can't use `&` the way you did, since that's used to concatenate strings.  You need `AndAlso`.

Try this

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "06:00:01 PM" AndAlso TextBox2.Text = "02:00:01 PM" Then
        ''# This is Valid
    Else
        ''# Sorry, Try Again
    End If
End Sub
```

Though I would suggest using the built in ASP.NET validation... I'm not sure if you have to validate those times exactly, but you could try a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) and a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) instead.

This *could* be your Regex for the DateTime

```
"^((((([13578])|(1[0-2]))[\-\/\s]?(([1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|((([469])|(11))[\-\/\s]?(([1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(30)))|(2[\-\/\s]?(([1-9])|([1-2][0-9]))))[\-\/\s]?\d{4})(\s((([1-9])|(1[02]))\:([0-5][0-9])((\s)|(\:([0-5][0-9])\s))([AM|PM|am|pm]{2,2})))?$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

`If TextBox1 = "06:00:01 PM" & TextBox2.Text = "02:00:01 PM" Then`

To:

`If TextBox1.Text = "06:00:01 PM" AndAlso TextBox2.Text = "02:00:01 PM" Then`